Calculate Amount Saved From Paying Interest-Only Payments vs Letting Interest Capitalize

Juan has finished a 4-year degree using a direct unsubsidized student loan of $32,000 at 3.77%. Nearing the end of his grace period, Juan applies for and receives a 36-month deferment with the option to pay monthly interest payments or have the interest capitalized at the end of the deferment period. Approximately how much money would Juan save over the course of the entire loan by paying interest payments during his deferment period?

The answer key has it at ~\$3900, but I get ~\$730


direct unsubsidized student loan...Nearing the end of his grace period

So interest accrues during 4yrs of college + 6mo grace period:
\$5428.80 accrued

36-month deferment...monthly interest payments or have the interest capitalized at the end of the deferment period

$3619.20 accrued

how much money would Juan save over the course of the entire loan by paying interest payments during his deferment period

If Juan doesn't make interest-only payments, after the 7.5yr (36mo deferment + 48mo non-payment period while in school + 6mo grace period), the interest that would capitalize on a standard 10yr student loan is \$9048.00.
Adding on \$9048 to the borrowed amount of \$32000, the total amount paid would be \$49334.00.
Adding only the interest in the original 54mo, the total amount paid would be \$44984.47. Adding the \$3619 of monthly interest payments paid brings the total to \$48603.67.
Subtracting these 2 figures brings it to \$730.60.
Even if you didn't subtract the monthly interest payments the difference would be \$4,349.80, which again isn't close to the answer key's answer of ~\$3900, but that would be the closest option of the ones provided.

I'll also add that this was a question high schoolers got, just insanity.

I followed you until you computed the total amounts paid. Where do these formulas come from?

That’s the standard equation to calculate the monthly payment on a loan: Principal(rate)(1+rate)^time / [(1+rate)^time - 1] and then times by the number of months to get total repayment.

My guess is that the high school students were given a lot of information about terminology that the general math community don't know and also given assumptions that make the question more or less of a real-world situation before this question was asked. For example, was the 32,000 loaned out in four equal payments of 8,000 each year or thrown at the college at the start of year one? The student seems to be billed monthly, but does interest accrue monthly or daily when capitalization begins? Do monthly payments remain the same over all ten years?

That’s all there is to the question sadly.
